# How to send whole result of the Cassandra query to the socket with netcat

Tags: sockets, cassandra, apache-flink, cassandra-3.0, netcat

I wanted to send data to the socket that my Flink program can read it from socket.

As this guidance https://stackoverflow.com/a/53943644/6640504 I did that with:

```
cqlsh -e “select * from tableName;” -k mykeyspace Ipaddress 9042 | 
 nc -lk portNumber
```

and my Flink program read data from socket without any errors.

Now I have a new issue which is Cassandra send data to the socket page by page and the  Flink program just receive one page. **I don’t know how to send another page automatically.**

I disabled “paging” in Cassandra with “paging off”; but It showed me this error:

> ReadFailure: Error from server: code=1300 [Replica(s) failed to 
>   execute read] message="Operation failed - received 0 responses and 1
>
> > failures" info={'failures': 1, 'received_responses': 0, >'required_responses': 1, 'consistency': 'ONE'}

Would you please help me how I can send the whole result of this query `“select * from tableName;”` to the socket for the Flink program to use it?

Comment: Check your Cassandra logs. Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37114455/reading-error-in-cassandra

Comment: I checked the log, it said "some operation time out".

Comment: How exactly did you go about trying "paging off" ?

Comment: I tested two ways, first, in cqlsh shell I wrote "paging off";but I recognized that the "paging off" did not affect the whole Cassandra. So, I wrote this command: "cqlsh -e “select * from tableName;” -k mykeyspace Ipaddress 9042 paging off | 
 nc -lk portNumber" and it did not do any thing special.